# Fluid sim problrms :C

Tags: fluid-simulation

Ok guys,  Im not sure, if i understanded  the basic system of fluid simulations in blender. So to my case, this hemisphere is assigned as fluid, the bowl as obstacle. Now I would assign the box as domain, but when i dont do that, the fluid flows only at the ground not in the bowl (only around it) If someone could help, I would extremely enjoy it.

[image: initial situation]

[image: after i made the cube to a fluid]

Answer (score -1):

You would really want to consider changing the file location that your simulation bakes to. This could be another simulation you tested that didn't work. Try changing the location to a file on your computer (not "//cache fluid") because that is a .tmp location.